# How to install latest version of imagick on centos 5.8 64bit using bash

Tags: bash, centos5, php5, imagemagick

How can I download and install latest version of imagick on centos 5.8 64bit using bash for php 5.4.

```
>yum info php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ellogroup.com
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror.ellogroup.com
 * updates: mirror.ellogroup.com
Installed Packages
Name       : php
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 5.4.3
Release    : 1.el5.remi
Size       : 8.8 M
Repo       : installed
Summary    : The PHP HTML-embedded scripting language. (PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor)
URL        : http://www.php.net/
License    : PHP
Description: PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it
           : easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages. PHP also
           : offers built-in database integration for several commercial and
           : non-commercial database management systems, so writing a
           : database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common
           : use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.
           :
           : The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP
           : language to Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific version requirement for ImageMagick?

ImageMagick is part of the distribution, so `yum install ImageMagick.x86_64` will download ImageMagick. 

If you have php 5.4, that's not part of CentOS 5.8, so check to see where that came from with `yum info php`.

To install PHP support,

```
yum install ImageMagick
yum install ImageMagick-devel
pecl install imagick
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have updated the question above.

Comment: Your php is from the [REMI repository](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/). Try running the `yum install ImageMagick` to see if it works. If not, see if there's a corresponding package in that repository.

Comment: its seems install correctly. but i can't find any "so" file so that i can configure php.ini file...   convert -h
Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 05/07/12 Q16 file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8/doc/index.html
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2006 ImageMagick Studio LLC

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: while runing last command pecl install imagick i am geting following error running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed

Comment: `yum install php-devel`

Comment: Ewwhite, getting following error
php-devel-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-34.el5_8 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-34.el5_8 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 (updates)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.

Comment: I run yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-devel and it is installed. but now I am geting following error while runing pecl install imagick.  checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/var/tmp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed

Comment: I provided list of commands which I used to isntall imagick. I am accepting your question because you gave me a good start. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install ImageMagick
yum install ImageMagick-devel
yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-devel
yum --enablerepo=remi install ImageMagick2
yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-pecl-imagick
```

[pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/) This is excellent site to find any package and installing it.

Comment: I used above commands to install Imagick imagemagick on centos 5.8 for php 5.4